# Commutative ring can be homomorphically mapped onto field

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, field-theory

During my algebra lecture, my lecturer used the fact that any nontrivial commutative ring can be homomorphically mapped onto a field. Is the statement true? How to show that?

Thanks

Comment: Hint: Does every commutative ring have a maximal ideal?

Comment: Do I make the right reasoning? Every commutative ring has maximal ideal, so the quotient ring with respect to that ideal is a field and it is enough to take natural homomorphism, which map the considered ring on the quotient ring?

Comment: @mezhang If the lecturer made that statement, he/she is assuming that rings he/she considers are unital, which is an assumption many people do.

Comment: @mezhang it doesn't *need* to have an identity, but having an identity *suffices*. You can have a ring without identity that has maximal ideals.

Comment: @mezhang Are you unaware that many books define "Ring" as having identity? There is a term "rng" for rings without identity....

Comment: @michael you've got the right idea. Would you mind writing a solution to your own question?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Indeed, in our definition ring has 1.

Comment: Yes, that answer suffices. Note that the existence of a maximal ideal is equivalent to the axiom of choice, so it is a "big hammer" to pull out in a proof.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Every nontrivial commutative (unital) ring $R$ has a maximal ideal, $\mathcal m$, and the natural map $R\to R/\mathcal m$ is an onto map from $R$ to a field.

The existence of a maximal ideal for an arbitrary non-trivial commutative ring is equivalent to the Axiom of Choice.